# How to read and write HTML to a file delimited by \n spaces?

Tags: python, html, file-io

I have an HTML file with `\n` spaces separating each element tag. We'll call this HTML file `results_cache.html`. I'd like to read `results_cache.html` with Python and then write its contents into another file, `hopeful.html`.

However, when writing the contents, I'd like to start a new line in `hopeful.html` each time a `\n` pops up. I was under the impression that Python would naturally do this; unfortunately, the entire HTML prints on one line only.

Here is my code:

```
lines = [str(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in open('results_cache.html')]

final_cache = open('hopeful.html','w')
for line in lines:
    final_cache.write(str(line))

final_cache.close()
```

This is a snapshot of what `hopeful.html` looks like:

`'<table>\n    <!-- ngRepeat: attempt in vm.getdate() -->    <tr ng-repeat="attemp...`

...with nothing else below it.

One thing I would like to point out is that the entire line is wrapped with single quotes. I don't know if this effects the outcome or not.

The HTML was scraped off a website using Selenium Webdriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop around the "open('results_cache.html')" is not iterating a line at a time, but it is iterating a character at a time.

```
with open('results_cache.html') as readfile:
    htmlfile = readfile.readlines()

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in htmlfile]
```

Or you could do it down and dirty:

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('results_cache.html').readlines()]
```

But using the "with" statement is better for proper cleanup should exceptions happen when using file operations.

Comment: A happy medium might be to have a `lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in readfile.readlines()]` in side a `with` block.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, I was iterating a character at a time. I'm getting myself acquainted with `with` and `readfile` now, because the usage of both apparently did the trick.